# Django model form field language is not changing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I am using django 2.2. and python 3.6. Bootstrap 4.
I have a template and crispy form inserted in template.
This form is created from model.
There is an imagefield field in model.

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="staff/", null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Fotoğraf"))
```

The crispyform is creating the field in the template but the language shown in the field is english. But i want to show turkish language.
The Choose File and Browse should be turkish.
So i changed settings.py as;

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr-tur'
```

But still it is written Choose File and Browse in the field in the page.

[image]

You can see in the screenshot that everything is Turkish language except "Choose File" and "Browse".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. First of all to change "Choose File" part:

Add a script that will change the label textContent,

```
<script>
var input = document.getElementById('id_photo');
var label = input.labels[1];
label.textContent = 'Dosya Seçin'
</script>
```

Secondly to change Browse part you have to edit **bootstrap.min.css** and change **custom-file-label** parts ***content:"Browse"*** to ***content:"What ever you want"*** there may be multiple content:"Browse" definitions, change all.

Answer (score 1):

"Choose file" and "Browse" don't become translated, because this is a part of bootstrap generated fields.

You can try to create pseudo class as described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#file-browser) in **Translating or customizing the strings** section. Shortly, as CSS code it should be like this:

```
$custom-file-text: (
  en: "Browse",
  es: "Elegir"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Django's default language in built-in forms, by including `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE`, in `settings.py`